# Design best practice - should an object own what is passed to its constructor?

Tags: oop

I have the following class:

```
public class SqlCeEventStore: EventStore
{
  private EventStoreDB db;

  public SqlCeEventStore(EventStoreDB db)
  {
    this.db = db;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    db.Dispose();
  }
}
```

My problem is this: am I correct in disposing the `EventStoreDB` in the `Dispose` method of my class, given that it was passed to it in the constructor (and thus, might conceivably be reused after my class is disposed)?

That is, if I dispose it I mandate that the correct usage of my class is:

```
using (var store = new SqlCeEventStore(new EventStoreDB)){
{
  //...
}
```

but I can see this alternative call being used:

```
using (var db = new EventStoreDB())
using (var store = new SqlCeEventStore(db))
{
  //...
}
```

in which case I should *not* dispose of the `EventStoreDB` from the `SqlCeEventStore` class.

Are there any arguments for one style or the other? I want to pick one and stick to it, and I'd rather not flip a coin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no rule to this, but yes I would agree that since the object was created outside your scope and was passed to you, you don't own it.

If you had created it, then you should have all rights to do whatever you like to (with documenting the expected behavior for the callers)

This is the classical [composition vs aggregation](http://tcle.wordpress.com/2008/05/20/aggregation-vs-composition-a-review-on-uml) stuff.

Comment: Ahhh... thanks. I must confess that the "composition vs aggregation" difference was never clear to me.

Comment: @Marcel: Yeah thats a tricky definition which is not easy to perceive. You situation is the way to see it. BTW is it clear now ? ;)

Comment: Yes, it is :) I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the EventStoreDB is owned by SqlEventStore (ie is part of its composition), it should be constructed by or be merged with the SqlEventStore class.

If it has uses outside the scope of the SqlEventStore lifetime then it should be created and disposed by the external code.

Comment: Good point. I prefer to inject in the constructor the objects a class depends on, so I can't do that, but without that rule you'd be correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule here, and IMHO, there should not be one either. Different objects have different lifespans, and the most general guideline would be to make sure that objects are managed consistently according to their lifespans, and that lifespans are as short as possible.

You could try to use the following as a guideline (but don't be afraid to deviate when you need to): *Dispose of an object in the same scope as you allocate it.* This guideline is suitable for many scenarios, and it is exactly what the `using` statement simplifies.

If you have long-lived objects without an obvious disposal point, don't worry. That's normal. However, ask yourself this: Do I really need this object to live for as long as it does? Is there some other way I can model this to make the lifespan shorter? If you can find another way that makes the lifespan shorter, that generally makes the object more manageable, and should be preferred.

But again, there is not any "one true rule" here.

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** pick one and stick to it. The user can always choose what ever he wants.

However, keep in mind that you are not responsible as a class of disposing objects passed through the constructor.

---

## note

The coming is really silly to discuss because `if you want to impose initiation of the class using *new SqlCeEventStore(new EventStoreDB))*` then why don't you remove this EventStoreDB parameter and instantiate the variable db inside your constructor.

## Workaround

There is a workaround -check this:

```
public myClass {
    //do not make the constructor public //hide it
    private myClass(EventStoreDB db){
        this.db = db;
    }
    //make a public constructor that will call the private one in the way you want
    public myClass(){
        this(myClass(new EventStoreDB()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer never to `new` objects inside a class, but to pass the dependencies in the constructor. The way you wrote it is valid, but it makes `myClass` harder to reuse.

Comment: in fact ... if a class extends your class he will have to use super and that is all (:

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that if one can reasonably imagine situations in which the constructed object would be the last thing in the universe that's interested in the passed-in object, as well as situations in which other things will want to keep using the passed-in object after the constructor is done with it, it may be desirable to have a constructor parameter which specifies whether the new object should take ownership of the object that was passed in.

Note that if the constructed object will be taking ownership of the passed-in object, it's important to make certain that object will be disposed even if the constructor throws an exception.  One way to do this would be to wrap the constructor call in a routine which will, in a "finally" block, dispose the passed-in object unless the constructor had completed successfully.